# Capture timing within parallel stream procesing

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, java-stream

I have a timer class that captures the unzip time and deserialization time for one of my processes. I am using parallel stream to do the above and would like to know the aggregate unzip time and deserialization time for all my objects

I am calling getVersionedRawDealNew()that does unzipping and deserialization for each deal.

The transformation time is much greater than the time taken to whole the whole of the method to process all my objects, which seems incorrect. Can you let me if the below is correct with the way the transformation timing is calculated?

```
    ProcessTimer timer = new ProcessTimer();
    List<VersionedRawDeal> versionedRawDeals = compressedVersionedRawDeals
            .parallelStream()
            .map(vrd -> getVersionedRawDealNew(vrd, timer))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    LOGGER.info("Time taken to process zipping : " + timer.getZipTime());
    LOGGER.info("Time taken to process transformation :" + timer.getTransformTime());
```

//getVersonedRawDealNew method

```
private VersionedRawDeal getVersionedRawDealNew(CompressedVersionedRawDeal compressedVerDeal, ProcessTimer timer){
    CompressedRawDeal compressedDeal = compressedVerDeal.rawDeal();
    DealVersion dealVersion = compressedVerDeal.dealVersion();

    long zipStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    final String dealXml = unzip(dealVersion, compressedDeal.getDealXmlBytes());
    long zipTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - zipStartTime;
    timer.addZipTime(zipTime);

    long transformStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    final RawDeal rawDeal = RawDealTransformers.getRawDealTransformerFor(compressedDeal.getSourceSystem())
            .transformDeal(compressedDeal.getSourceEvent(), dealXml);

    long transformTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - transformStartTime;
    timer.addTransformTime(transformTime);
    return ImmutableVersionedRawDeal.builder().dealVersion(dealVersion).rawDeal(rawDeal).build();
}
```

//Process Timer

```
public class ProcessTimer {

    private AtomicLong zipTime;
    private AtomicLong transformTime;

    public ProcessTimer(){
        this.zipTime = new AtomicLong();
        this.transformTime = new AtomicLong();
    }

    public void addZipTime(long time){
        this.zipTime.addAndGet(time);
    }

    public void addTransformTime(long time){
        this.transformTime.addAndGet(time);
    }

    public long getZipTime(){
        return zipTime.get();
    }

    public long getTransformTime(){
        return transformTime.get();
    }
}
```

**Output**

I don't get the correct time calculation as I have a timer that wraps the above call, i.e within a parent method and the time take to run the whole process is lesser than my transform time. My timer for the parent method which encompasses the unzip and transform time should be greater than my transform time, which is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

The transformation time is bigger than the whole method time, because you are using parallel stream which creates parallel tasks(tasks that run at the same time). You sum time of the parallel tasks that are running at the same time.

```
0--------------------------------------------------------  
   |                        |                             |
   |                        |                             | 
   |(1 parallel taks 3sec)  |                             |  
                            | (2 parallel task 4sec)      | 
5---------------------------------------------------------|(the whole metod took 5 sec)
```

The method took 5(sec), one of the parallel task took 3sec, and second took 4sec, so the transformation time is 7 which is bigger than overall method time 5 sec.

Comment: That's Interesting, so what would be the best way to calculate the actual time of transformation alone? Any suggestions?

Comment: @megan measure execution of each separately and then aggregate, or just switch to sequential streams and look at the overall time for serialised operations

Comment: This depends, what you have now is the "real time" that your transformation took. If you want to know how does it took "one" transformation you can divide the time with the number of deals and you will get the average time for one transformation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @HPCS. the problem I have is my deals can be of different sizes, and the time it takes to transform two different deals could vary quite a lot. So taking one or two deals as the benchmark and extrapolating it across a number of deals might not work well.Overall, my method is faster when I parallelise it to doing in sequentially, but the transformation timing is totally different to when I parallelise because of threads interleaving and completing at a later time.

Comment: @GrzegorzPiwowarek I guess it is not going to be possible for me to calculate the transformation time within my parallel streams . I wanted to know what percentage of my total time is taken by transformation vs unzipping within my parallel processing.

Comment: You can add new timer  that will collect timing for the whole getVersionedRawDealNew you save the time at the beginning of the  method and store the time at the end of the method. At the end you will have 3 timers one for the total time of the getVersionedRawDealNew, one for unziping and one for the transformation(as you already have). Now you can compute the  percentage ratio  of the total time taken by transformation vs unzipping.